# How to re-write Java 8 Streaming method?

Tags: java, set, compare, entity, java-stream

I have the following `entity` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KENNEL")
public class KENNEL{


    //other fields and vars

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private Set<Dog> dogs;

    public DateTime getOldestDogInKennel(){
            return dogList.stream().min(Comparator.comparing(Dog::getBirthday))
                .get().getBirthday();
        }


}
```

How can I re-write the `getOldestDogInKennel` method so that it works **without** having to use the java 8 streaming?

Note that this entity **does not** implement the comparable interface.

Comment: Create a for loop iterate over each element and use the Comparator to compare the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using Collections min get the min element of Dog Object

```
Collections.min(dogList, new Comparator<Dog>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Dog o1, Dog o2) {
        return o1.getBirthday().compareTo(o2.getBirthday()));
    }

}).getBirthday()
```

Comment: Pleas enote the entitiy class does not implement comparable, thanks

Comment: @java123999: Please note that this answer does not assume the entitiy class to implement comparable, thanks

Comment: Does it not need to do considering that it uses compareTo? Also, could you please show the full method as I need to add it to my entity? thanks

Comment: @java123999: did you ever try to understand the code of this answer? Do you see that there is a comparator implementation for the `Dog` instances, which will compare the values returned by `getBirthday()`, just like the comparator created via `Comparator.comparing(Dog::getBirthday)` in your question?

Comment: @Holger I did try to understand it. however it is not a full method, i.e. public void .... ?

Comment: @java123999: this is a site for *programmers*. We assume that questioners are able to read and understand code and to integrate a solution into their code on their own. If you understand, what [`Collections.min(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#min-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) does, you should be able to do that. This is not a spoon-feed service.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that would do;

```
Date oldest = new Date();
for (int i=0; i< doglist.size(); i++){
   if (doglist.get(i).getBirthday().compareTo(oldest) < 0)   
      oldest = doglist.get(i).getBirthday();
}

return oldest;
```

Comment: is it not possible to use the comparator?

Comment: it works fine with compareTo(). If the left date is older than the right one, then compareTo() returns -1

Comment: oo yeah, I didn't notice that when I first wrote it :) sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: is there no way that I can not use comparable for this?

Comment: How can I do this without implementing the comparable interface in the entity?

Comment: @java123999 you can use a lambda expression. I will update my answer.

Comment: @Holger since you are totally right, I removed that code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you want to do later in the program. So this methods has the oldest `dog` at the end of the method.

```
public DateTime getOldestDogInKennel() {
    if (dogList.size() <= 0) { return null; }

    Dog dog = dogList.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
        Dog d = dogList.get(i);
        if (d.getBirthday().compareTo(dog.getBirthday()) < 0)) {
            dog = d;
        }
    }

    return dog.getBirthday();
}
```

Without `Compareable` interface use:

```
public DateTime getOldestDogInKennel() {
    if (dogList.size() <= 0) { return null; }

    Dog dog = dogList.get(0);
    for (int i = 1; i < dogList.size(); i++) {
        Dog d = dogList.get(i);
        if (d.getBirthday().getTime() < dog.getBirthday().getTime()) {
            dog = d;
        }
    }

    return dog.getBirthday();
}
```

Comment: How can I do this without implementing the comparable interface in the entity?

Comment: You use instead: `d.getBirthday().getTime() < dog.getBirthday().getTime()`

Comment: Ok thanks, and this will loop through each value in the list?

Comment: yes, because there is no `return` or `break` in the loop.

Comment: I added it to the answer

Comment: `dogList.size() == null` is unlikely to work. Besides that, it’s not a recommended strategy to return `null` in case of an empty list, when the original code threw an exception in that case.

Comment: @Holger the null check is a very good advice :D The problem with returning `null` i have known but because i don't know the project i don't know what is best to return

Comment: Well, the original behavior is buried deep down in the question’s code, but since it unconditionally invokes `get()` on an `Optional`, it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` is case of an empty source. If in doubt, reproducing the original code’s behavior is a good choice.